# Использоване chat-gpt для формирования облаков тегов

Tags: chatgpt

Корректно ли использовать chat-gpt для формирования облака тегов на основе некотрого текста?

Например, есть список отзывов о товаре. Мы берем его и склеиваем их в один текст. Далее используем этот текст и просим chat-gpt сформировать облако тегов, состоящих из 5и частых биграмм.

Comment: Если вам возвращается приемлимый для вас ответ, то почму бы и нет?